# WPF Window still visible as a maximizable rectangle despite setting Visibility to Hidden and WindowState to Minimized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need to hide the window completely and not allow it to be double-clicked to be maximized, as that changes the window to be resizable despite the ResizeMode being set to NoResize and WindowStyle set to None.  That double click seems to change the settings irreversibly (the window edges are always adjustable after that double click), and that is unnacceptible in this case - I need it to either not be double clickable, or, preferrably, completely invisible when it's minimized.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how can it still be visible and clickable when it is hidden? What .NET and Windows version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden`on your Visibility setting.

Here's the documentation on what's the difference between the two: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still seems to show a title bar-like thing when minimized using collapsed, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can set WindowStyle="None" on your Window when it is collapsed. This will remove the title bar.

Comment: It is written in the question that `Visibility="Hidden"`, `WindowState="Minimized"`, `ResizeMode="NoResize"` and `WindowStyle="None"`. Which is why I don't understand how is anything still visible at all with all those settings and `Hidden` or `Collapsed` visibility.

Comment: Right, I guess we're missing some details on how his windows is getting hidden.